# IIS 7.5 ASP.NET: Access to path is Denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have gone through several forums to help solve this issue and it seems the solution is granting full control to DefaultAppPool Identity but unfortunately its not working on my end. I am testing the application in my local machine(Windows 7) and the application uses windows authentication and the application is not using any impersonation in web.config file.

This is what I have done following other possible solutions online: 
Granted full access to: DefaultAppPool,Network Service, IUSR, ASP.NET v4.0

Below is the error I get even after granting necessary access:

[image]

Any suggestions as to how to go about fixing this? thanks!

Comment: uploading error image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Solved the problem Selecting in IIS Authentication Module and setting the application pool identity in the anonymous Authentication like in the picture

[image: Authentication module]

Comment: ok then try to create a new appPool and change the user with your username. (you will have the right to access to your storage). you computer is in a Domain?

Comment: I will try that, yes it is.

Comment: that didn't work either, I will try to recreate the project and try these steps again. Thanks for your help, greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try also to move your root folder away from the c: Move for eg. In c:\wwwroot\yourproject because the writing in c: Is very restricted

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe :) I recreated the project followed these steps and now its running properly

Answer (score 1):

The security settings for the folder "TestRelease" may have some values that are preventing you from reading files in that folder.  Go to your C:/ and right click the TestRelease folder, then go to Properties.  Navigate to the Security tab and check to see if any of the Permissions are set to Deny or if somehow the Read permission is not set to Allow.